# Why did EOSio exclude all EOS ERC20-token holders who didn't register before 2st of June 2018?

Tags: tokens, exchange, eosio.token, governance

They have made my ERC-20 EOS tokens non-transferable, so now the money I invested is lost. On my Trezor (MEW - MyEthereumWallet)

Are there any official statements of the reasons to the malignant decision of this exclusion?

Comment: there was no malignancy. can you try inputting your Ethereum pubic key here https://eosauthority.com/account and see if you get an account back

Answer (score 2):

There is a fallback method available for those who did not register before the deadline. The link below should be a good starting point to access your funds via the EOS blockchain:

https://eosauthority.com/blog/how_to_generate_your_EOS_fallback_key_from_ethereum_private_key

Comment: That is not exactly a direct answer to my question, but it may help me. However, I have a Trezor wallet, so I don't know how to get my Private key from there.

Comment: You'll need to use the mnemonic seed for the trezor, preferably on an offline computer, to extract your ETH private keys, and then use those to go through the process. You'll also want to move all of your funds to a different seed on the trezor as well, just to be 100% safe. There's more info here https://www.reddit.com/r/TREZOR/comments/8ozs45/how_to_get_eth_private_key_for_eos_if_you_missed/